# Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment:

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-deployment

helm install failing with the below error

command

```
helm install --name helloworld helm
```

Below is the error once I ran above command

```
Error: release usagemetrics failed: Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: v1.Deployment.Spec: v1.DeploymentSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Containers: []v1.Container: v1.Container.LivenessProbe: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found 9, error found in #10 byte of ...|ssProbe":9001,"name"|..., bigger context ...|"imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","livenessProbe":9001,"name":"usagemetrics-helm","ports":[{"containe|...
```

Below is the deployment.yaml file i feel the issue in liveness and probeness configuration .

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: release-name-helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: release-name-helm
      release: release-name
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: release-name-helm
        release: release-name
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: release-name-helm
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          image: hellworld
          ports:
            - name: "http"
              containerPort: 9001
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: release-name-helm
            - secretRef:
                name: release-name-helm
          livenessProbe:
            9001
          readinessProbe:
            9001
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the `livenessProbe` and `readynessProbe` that are both wrong.

An example of `livenessProbe` of http from the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) is:

```
livenessProbe

  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: 8080
    httpHeaders:
      - name: Custom-Header
        value: Awesome
    initialDelaySeconds: 3
    periodSeconds: 3
```

Your yamls if you only want to have a check of the port should be like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: release-name-helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: release-name-helm
      release: release-name
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: release-name-helm
        release: release-name
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: release-name-helm
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          image: hellworld
          ports:
            - name: "http"
              containerPort: 9001
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: release-name-helm
            - secretRef:
                name: release-name-helm
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 9001
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 9001
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
```

Comment: sine you have named your port in the `ports`, in the `port` section of `livenessProbe` and  `readinessProbe` you could use `http` (the name of the port) instead of 9001.